# Quelle est l'étymologie de « à vous laisser baba » ? Relation avec « jaw-dropping »

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques, étymologie, locutions, cinéma

> C'est un film avec un réalisme *à vous laisser baba*.

Cette locution est-elle l'équivalent de *jaw-dropping* en anglais ? Quelle est son étymologie ?

Comment: Il y a aussi la locution « à en tomber baba » (C'est un film avec un réalisme à en tomber baba.); elle signifie la même chose sauf que, peut être, l'ahurissement dont on parle serait plus intense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baba) indique une origine onomatopéïque. Sinon, la proximité avec é**ba**hi, (bouche) bée et a**ba**sourdi a peut-être joué.

C'est une locution familière relativement répandue.

Sa signification est effectivement celle de *jaw dropping*, c'est à dire qui a la bouche bée. D'ailleurs, le TLFi indique que l'onomatopée a aussi un lien avec la bouche (babine, babiller).

Comment: Est-ce une locution répandue ? D'où vient la relation avec jaw dropping ?

Comment: https://www.linguee.com/french-english/translation/laisser+baba.html

Comment: @Dimitris Il n'y a aucune évidence de relation avec jaw-dropping; mais si vous voulez dire « qu'est-ce que viennent faire les machoires là-dedans? » cela semble facile à comprendre à moins que vous n'ayez jamais pu voir quelqu'un dans un état de grande surprise  à l'instant même ou cette surprise commence à se manifester et même parfois plus tard : le comportement plutôt largement répandu (pas qu'en Grand Bretagne) qui consiste à ouvrir grand la bouche et la laisser ainsi deux ou trois secondes  est l'explication; les machoires en s'ouvrant se déplacent vers le bas, tombent, d'où « dropping ».

Comment: dimitris, ce n'est pas une relation, c'est une equivalence, ne cherchez pas un lien